# Symfony2: PHPUnit Testing-> @dataProvider sends no multipleArray

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, dataprovider

I make UnitTesting for my application.

I have a save saveArticleIds() Method and I wrote a testing for it -> testSaveArticelIds(). I have an dataProvider articelIdsArray() whith a multiple array. The function need that array exact like this.

```
/**
 *
 * @dataProvider articleIdsArray
 *
 */
public function testSavearticleIds($articleIds) {

    $articleIdObjekt = new ArticleIdHandler();
    $result = $articleIdObjekt->saveArticleIds($articleIds,false);

    $this->assertTrue($result);
}

public function articleIdsArray() {
    return array(
      array(
            10552 => 10552,
            14314 => 14314,
            21034 => 21034,
            22739 => 22739,
            34568 => 34568,
            34572 => 34572,
            35401 => 35401,
            38292 => 38292,
            55141 => 55141,
            161764 => 161764,
            181589 => 181589
       )
    );
}
```

When I run my test, I get this Error:

```
There was 1 error: 1) My\Bundle\ArticleBundle\Tests\Article\ArticleIdHandlerTest::testSaveArticleIds 
with data set #0  (10552, 14314, 21034, 22739, 34568, 34572, 35401, 38292, 55141, 161764, 181589)
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Why does it show the array like I have no keys in the array? I need the array exact like in my dataProvider! Any idea?? THANKS A LOT FOR YOU HELP!!!

Comment: Please provide the source code for `saveArticleIds($articleIds, false)`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this:

```
public function articleIdsArray()
{
    return 
    array(
        array(
            array(
                10552  => 10552,
                14314  => 14314,
                21034  => 21034,
                22739  => 22739,
                34568  => 34568,
                34572  => 34572,
                35401  => 35401,
                38292  => 38292,
                55141  => 55141,
                161764 => 161764,
                181589 => 181589
            )
        )
    );
}
```

The reason is that the first level of the array nesting is the set of data provided for each round of tests, the second level represents the arguments provided to testSavearticleIds, in the same order as in the parameter list of the function (in your example there is only one argument), the last level is just the test array itself.

Hope this helps...

Comment: No, unfonrtunately not...! Now I get an error in my working class which is called in my ArticleIdHandler Class.

Comment: Could that possibly a 'legit' test failure? When I tried the code I used:
`public function testSavearticleIds($articleIds){print_r($articleIds); $this->assertTrue(true); }
    

and got as output the expected array...

Sorry about the formatting, could get it to display nicely...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
/**
 * @dataProvider articleIdsArray
 */
public function testSavearticleIds($articleIds)
{
    $articleIdObjekt = new ArticleIdHandler();
    $result = $articleIdObjekt->saveArticleIds($articleIds,false);

    $this->assertTrue($result);
}

public function articleIdsArray()
{
    return array(
        'scenario_one' => 10552,
        'scenario_two' => 14314,
        ...,
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You doesn't need to use @dataProvider in your example.

Define your method like this

```
public function getArticleIdsArray() {
  return array(
     10552 => 10552,
     14314 => 14314,
     21034 => 21034,
     22739 => 22739,
     34568 => 34568,
     34572 => 34572,
     35401 => 35401,
     38292 => 38292,
     55141 => 55141,
     161764 => 161764,
     181589 => 181589
  );
}
```

and use it in your test

```
public function testSavearticleIds($articleIds) {

    $articleIdObjekt = new ArticleIdHandler();
    $result = $articleIdObjekt->saveArticleIds($this->getArticleIdsArray(),false);
    $this->assertTrue($result);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, get the same error but 11 times for each Id! Too bad.

Comment: Error says: Data set #10552 is invalid.

Comment: Don't write this @dataProvider articleIdsArray